# Member initialization in swift

Tags: constructor, swift2

In C++ we can use a member initialization list you initialize class member like:

```
object::object():_a(0), _b(0){}
```

Is there a way to do this same thing in swift(2.0)?

Comment: this syntax is the "initialization list" but i don't know how to recreate it in swift

Comment: There's no such syntax in Swift; it's not needed. Initialise in the declaration or in your initialiser. (And those are not declarations, they're initialisations.)

Comment: What is "this same thing"? C++ is C++. Swift is Swift. They have nothing to do with each other. If you want to use Swift, use _Swift_. The question is pointless and meaningless. Just think about what you want to do _in Swift_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For swift to require you to init class member means that the class member is an optionnal, you have to supply proper init in the class init.
For example :

```
class PhAuthenticationToken : NSObject {

    var authenticationToken : NSString
    var expiry : NSDate?
    var permissions : NSString

    init(token : NSString, secondsToExpiry seconds : NSTimeInterval, permissions perms : NSString) {

        self.authenticationToken = token
        if (seconds != 0) {
            self.expiry = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: seconds)
        }
        self.permissions = perms
    }
}
```

You should check the official documentation :
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html